# batch/CMD move does not work with folders

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd, move

I have a simple .bat (move.bat) file in the SendTo folder which moves files and directories from any location to a specified folder by using the context menu. This worked on XP. In Windows 7 however i get an access denied error.
It doesn't even work with cmd opened as admin (runas).

content of move.bat:

```
move %1 c:\specifiedfolder
```

Comment: Does it fail for any folder? Are you sure you have access to the folder that is failing?

Comment: Yes it fails for any folder. I set full permission to Everyone on a test folder but it didn't work either.

Comment: It works for me on Windows 7. Are you sure you have write access to `C:\specifiedfolder`?

Comment: yes, i double checked it. It does work for single files but not for a directory

Comment: Do you have authority to create folders in `C:\specifiedfolder`? Do you have authority to delete the source folder? What happens if you try to move it using Windows Explorer?

Comment: Q1,Q2: yes, Q3: i can move the folder with no problems.

Comment: You could temporarily replace the content of your batch file with the following `echo on && echo %CMDCMDLINE% && echo move %1 c:\specifiedfolder && pause`. Then look at the command as it is actually executed. There might be some issues with spaces (which your batch doesn't handle), directories attempted to move across volumes (which is not supported by `move`), etc.

Comment: You should have this --> `move "%~1" "c:\specifiedfolder"` to support long filename elements, but you can't create a folder in the root of C:\ as a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

Try to have the admin take ownership  with  `takeown /F <filename>`  (for files)  and
`takeown /f <foldername> /r /d y`  (for folders)   and then try to move the file or folder

after taking ownership set admin file permission to full control with the cacls utility 
:

```
cacls <folder> /T  /G admin:F
```

Comment: Althought the takeown command worked worked, i got the same error. This is the content of the batch script i tried:
takeown /f %1 /r /d Y
move %1 c:\somefolder

Comment: added an additional step to my suggestion

Comment: I've had the same problem as the OP and this did not fix it.  The commands WORK, but i still get access denied.  Something has changed in Windows7 that's causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue so did a bit of experimenting.

It seems that as of Windows 7, *ANY* open handle to the directory in windows will cause an access denied. This includes explorer open in that directory, and people using that directory over the network.

You *can* use rename if you are renaming a directory but otherwise keeping the path the same.  This will work EVEN if there is an open handle such as an explorer window  open within that directory (the path within the window will get refreshed)
Which is a  good solution if you are just trying to backup information as a fail-safe, but not anything you are likely to use for automated network backing up etc.

if the permissions settings did not work, then it is almost certainly an open handle from explorer, an executable running from that directory or some thing similar.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 you have to run the batch as administrator. But then make sure to change dir to homedir at begginning of your script, coz current dir will be different than what it should be when you run as admin..
Alternatively you can start a cmd window with admin rights then you can type or drag&drop batch files into it...

another way to do is to xcopy with /R option, then delete source... Or simply use robocopy

```
robocopy %1 c:\specifiedfolder /E /IS /MOVE
```

but still you need to dele skipped files...

Comment: Executing the batch file with administrator rights only screws with the current path, but still gives the same "access denied" result.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of your files are opened by the system process. 
You should close all the files before attempting the move command